# Why doesn't this nested angular-ui-router work?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

This seems to comply with the documentation for nested states:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fp09uXZ8xM2suQBwvXr7

The nested states in the foregoing plunker did not work (which was easily seen by looking at the plunker) but do now because someone had the courage to actually look at plunker and offer help.

Comment: Please include at least the portion of the code necessary to understand your question in the question body, rather than behind a link.

Comment: Please take the time if you are interested in helping to bother to hit the link and look at the code. Using angular-ui-router is fairly complex and can't be described with a few code snippets.

Comment: My question is specific and meets the requirements. It is a question that is specific, e.g., why doesn't the plunker work, and it does include valid code. It runs! It seems that you want the code in stackoverflow where it doesn't run, which is anachronistic. Why use a simple editor when a real, live example can be provided.

Comment: Stack Overflow is intended to be a repository of knowledge *in and of itself*, useable in the future.  Your question needs to contain sufficient information to be a useful question in and of itself, even if your link breaks (say, plunker goes bankrupt).  You're more than welcome to discuss this on [meta], if you like, but this is a well worn subject around here.  (I didn't offer help because I haven't the slightest idea what's wrong with it, I'm not an angularjs expert.  Your thread came up in a [meta] discussion.)

Comment: [This thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code) is probably the best one to understand the policy and the reasons for it (it's about jsfiddle, but that's the same idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to allow for the link to Route1 to work, remove the forward space, like so:

```
<a href="#">Route 1</a>
```

In Route2.html remove the html file endings on the subroutes, like so:

```
<a href="#/route2/subroute21">Subroute 21</a>
<a href="#/route2/subroute22">Subroute 22</a>
<a href="#/route2/subroute23">Subroute 23</a>
```

That should do the trick. At least it did for me.